# Assigning functions to a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I have certain graph structure in my JS program where each node has specific functions associated to it.

**Graph Structure**

```
var g = {

  "alpha_1" : getNode("alpha"),
  "beta_1" : getNode("beta")
 ....

}
```

**getNode()** function

```
var getNode = function (type) {

        var obj = {

            'metaType': type,
            'config': Object,
            'data': {
                'loc': {'x': '', 'y': ''},
                'args': {'keys': [], 'values': []},
                'return': []
            },
            'in': [],
            'true': [],
            'false': [],
            'inLineId': [],
            'outLineTrueId': [],
            'outLineFalseId': []
            //'prototype': Object.prototype
        };


        switch (type) {

            case 'alpha':

                obj.data.args.keys.push('dataStore', 'filters', 'limit', 'data');
                obj.data.args.values['dataStore'] = '';
                obj.data.args.values['limit'] = 'FALSE';
                obj.data.args.values['data'] = 'FALSE';
                obj.data.args.values['filters'] = [];

                /**
                 * @param valueObj :{}  JSON Object with fields from, value, type
                 */
                obj.config.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'setDatastore', {
                    value: function (valueObj) {
                        obj.data.args.values['dataStore'] = valueObj;
                    },
                    enumerable: false,
                    configurable: true,
                });

                /**
                 * @param valuesArray :[]  Array with fields from, value, type
                 */
                obj.config.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'setReturnValues', {
                    value: function (valueArray) {
                        obj.data.args.values['return'].push.apply([], valueArray);
                    },
                    enumerable: false,
                    configurable: true,

                });
        case 'beta':

            /**
             * @param key
             * @param op =/>=/!=/<=/</>
             * @param valueObj :{}  JSON Object with fields from, value, type
             * @param next
             */
            obj.config.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'addFilter', {
                value: function (key, op, valueObj, next) {
                    obj.data.args.values['filters'].push(
                        {
                            'key': key,
                            'op': op,
                            'value': valueObj,
                            'next': next
                        }
                    );
                },
                configurable: true,

                enumerable: false
            });

..


    }

  return obj;
}
```

Then I tried to access the defined functions in the following manner,

```
g.alpha.config.setDatastore({"a":"b"});
```

but it gives me an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: g.alpha_1.config.setDatastore is not a function(…)

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: I think @tymeJV is right. The net result should be the same, though mine is deferred until you actually call the function. Maybe the issue lies within the `obj.config.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'setDatastore'`

Comment: `console.log(g.alpha)` and see what you get.

Comment: I get `Object {metaType: "alpha", data: Object, in: Array[0], true: Array[0], false: Array[0], config: function Object() …}`

Comment: can you please try changing `'config': Object` to `'config': new Object()` in your `getNode()` function

Comment: @eithedog I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: obj.config.defineProperty is not a function`

Comment: The problem is that you define: `g` with `alpha_1` property, but you're accessing it via `g.alpha`. I'm still unsure if the `defineProperty` usage is correct, but I'm not knowledgable about it to say one way or the other. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z0xj6xkk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

> `Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)`
>
> Parameters
>
> `obj` **The object on which to define the property**.
>
> `prop` The name of the property to be defined or modified.
>
> `descriptor` The descriptor for the property being defined or modified.

`obj.config.defineProperty(Object.prototype, ...)` will add the property to Object.prototype.

What you're looking for are: `Object.defineProperty(obj.config, ...)`

You also need to change `'config': Object,` to `'config': new Object(),`

```js
var getNode = function(type) {

  var obj = {
    'metaType': type,
    'config': new Object(),
    'data': {
      'loc': {
        'x': '',
        'y': ''
      },
      'args': {
        'keys': [],
        'values': []
      },
      'return': []
    },
    'in': [],
    'true': [],
    'false': [],
    'inLineId': [],
    'outLineTrueId': [],
    'outLineFalseId': []
      //'prototype': Object.prototype
  };


  switch (type) {
    case 'alpha':
      obj.data.args.keys.push('dataStore', 'filters', 'limit', 'data');
      obj.data.args.values['dataStore'] = '';
      obj.data.args.values['limit'] = 'FALSE';
      obj.data.args.values['data'] = 'FALSE';
      obj.data.args.values['filters'] = [];

      /**
       * @param valueObj :{}  JSON Object with fields from, value, type
       */
      Object.defineProperty(obj.config, 'setDatastore', {
        value: function(valueObj) {
          obj.data.args.values['dataStore'] = valueObj;
        },
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
      });

      /**
       * @param valuesArray :[]  Array with fields from, value, type
       */
      Object.defineProperty(obj.config, 'setReturnValues', {
        value: function(valueArray) {
          obj.data.args.values['return'].push.apply([], valueArray);
        },
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
      });
    case 'beta':

      /**
       * @param key
       * @param op =/>=/!=/<=/</>
       * @param valueObj :{}  JSON Object with fields from, value, type
       * @param next
       */
      Object.defineProperty(obj.config, 'addFilter', {
        value: function(key, op, valueObj, next) {
          obj.data.args.values['filters'].push({
            'key': key,
            'op': op,
            'value': valueObj,
            'next': next
          });
        },
        configurable: true,

        enumerable: false
      });
  }

  return obj;
}

var g = {
  "alpha_1": getNode("alpha"),
  "alpha_2": getNode("alpha"),
  "beta_1": getNode("beta")
}

g.alpha_1.config.setDatastore({
  "a": "b"
});
g.alpha_2.config.setDatastore({
  "a": "c"
});

//output
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(g.alpha_1.data.args.values['dataStore']);
document.body.innerHTML += "<br>" + JSON.stringify(g.alpha_2.data.args.values['dataStore']);
```

Comment: I had similar implementation before, it conflicted with jQuery. I will try this again .

Comment: That's what I thought, but OP's code still works somehow (by works, I mean - with yours, and with OP's code, the `g.alpha_1.config` has method `setDatastore`). I wonder if he's not defining `setDatastore` on all `Object`s instead of only on instance of `obj.config` object?

Comment: Yep, I define `setDatastore` in  couple of objects.

Comment: @eithedog Yes, that is correct. Adding a property to `Object.prototype` will make it accessable for all `Object`s, and that's not what we want to do here.

Comment: @Fawzan - with your code, you're actually defining different methods on `Object` "class", depending upon which condition your code goes to. With @Johan Karlsson code you'll be defining methods on the instances of `Object` for each of your elements within `g`. edit: @Johan Karlsson - yeah, I've tried it out for myself ;) it was some time I've dabbled with the `definerProperty` and wasn't sure how it could have been working in OP's code

Comment: with your answer can I create a function like `setDatastore` on two different objects?

Comment: @JohanKarlsson it works fine, but I have a  Fall-Through in the switch case of my actual code (which is large code base). So it assigns the last defined function and remove all the functions defined in previous `case`s.

Comment: @Fawzan Add `break;` at end of each `case:`?

Comment: well, I intentionally had the `Fall-through` to reduce the code. Otherwise I have to repeat a function 5 or 6 times.

Comment: @Fawzan Oh well I don't think I can help you without seeing that code, and maybe that doesn't belong to this question.

Comment: Yep. I will put up another question. Thanks for the support.